# Get Entity Class in Generic Spring Data Repository Fragment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add some custom functionality to a Spring Data Repository using the Repository composing features documented here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior

Specifically, I'm trying to create a generic interface and implementation I can use with many of my repositories which seem to be a valid approach given "Example 34. Fragments overriding" in the link above which shows just this scenario.

I have got my generic interface DynamicEntityGraph

```
public interface DynamicEntityGraph<T> {

    List<T> findAll(EntityGraph<T> entityGraph);

}
```

and the corresponding implementation

```
public class DynamicEntityGraphImpl<T> implements DynamicEntityGraph<T> {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(EntityGraph<T> entityGraph) {

        //EM Code Goes Here
        return null;
    }
}
```

which I then use in a repository like

```
@Repository
public interface SiteRepository extends CustomerScopedRepository<Site>, DynamicEntityGraph<Site> {
}
```

This part all works fine.

My issue is in the DynamicEntityGraphImpl I need to get the Class of T at runtime in order to create my Entity Manager queries. After extensive research, I've not been able to find a solution in which I can obtain the Class of T, despite it looking like a valid solution given it exists in the Spring Data JPA Docs.

I've read the source code of [JpaRepositoryFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/JpaRepositoryFactory.java) and can see the class is injected into the repository when it's constructed, but I'm not sure how to access this from the fragment.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

For my future self or other lost travellers on a similar path, I figured it out and here is the solution.

A similar question was asked on the Spring Data project and this clears up that fragments are actually [initialised as singletons](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2278) in the Spring context so it's not possible to pass the EntityInformation to them.

Note: If you're not trying to make a generic fragment then this isn't the right solution for you.

The solution is to then extend the JpaRepositoryFactory and JpaRepositoryFactoryBean with a little extra configuration.

```
public class MyJpaRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFragments getRepositoryFragments(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        RepositoryFragments fragments = super.getRepositoryFragments(metadata);

        if(DynamicEntityGraph.class.isAssignableFrom(metadata.getRepositoryInterface()))
        {
            JpaEntityInformation<?, Serializable> entityInformation = this.getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());
            fragments = fragments.append(RepositoryFragment.implemented(DynamicEntityGraph.class, new DynamicEntityGraphImpl(entityInformation, entityManager)));
        }

        return fragments;
    }
}
```

this simply checks if the repository being instantiated implements our interface and if it does we construct a new instance of our class, passing it the EntityInformation and EntityManger.

```
public class MyJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends JpaRepository<Object, Serializable>> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T , Object, Serializable> {

    public MyJpaRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new MyJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

and finally, we tell Spring Data to use this as our factory bean

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MyJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ApplicationApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

It's important to also mark your fragment interface as `@NoRepositoryBean` to prevent Spring from making a bean from it.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface DynamicEntityGraph<T> {

    List<T> findAll(EntityGraph<T> entityGraph);

}
```

I hope this saves you some time!

Answer (score 0):

I am using a utility object SubGraphUtil. SubGraphUtil is used to build the graph.
I also have a specification object for the where part

```
        public abstract class AbstractCustomRepository<T> {
    
        private static final String FETCH_GRAPH = "javax.persistence.fetchgraph";
        @PersistenceContext
        protected EntityManager entityManager;
        @Setter
        private Class<T> entityClass;
    
    
        /**
         * Permet de recuperer une liste d entites en choisissant le graphe et la specification
         *
         * @param subGraphUtilList
         * @param specification
         * @return une liste d entites en choisissant le graphe
         */
        public List<T> findAllWithGraphAndSpecification(List<SubGraphUtil> subGraphUtilList,
                                                        @Nullable Specification<T> specification) {
            EntityGraph<T> graph = buildEntityGraphFromUtil(subGraphUtilList);
            CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = getCriteriaQuery(specification);
            return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                    .setHint(FETCH_GRAPH, graph)
                    .getResultList();
        }
    
        /**
         * Permet de construire  EntityGraph
         *
         * @param subGraphUtilList
         * @return EntityGraph
         */
        private EntityGraph<T> buildEntityGraphFromUtil(List<SubGraphUtil> subGraphUtilList) {
            EntityGraph<T> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(entityClass);
            if (isNotEmpty(subGraphUtilList)) {
                subGraphUtilList.forEach(
                        subGraphUtil -> {
                            Subgraph<T> subgraph = graph.addSubgraph(subGraphUtil.getName());
                            if (isNotEmpty(subGraphUtil.getSubGraphUtilList())) {
                                subGraphUtil.getSubGraphUtilList()
                                        .forEach(
                                                childGraph -> addSubGraph(subgraph, childGraph)
                                        );
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
            return graph;
        }
}
```

Example of use in a repository

```
public class ContratCustomRepositoryImpl extends AbstractCustomRepository<Contrat>
        implements ContratCustomRepository {

    public ContratCustomRepositoryImpl() {
        super();
        setEntityClass(Contrat.class);
    }
}

public interface ContratCustomRepository {

    List<Contrat> findAllWithGraphAndSpecification(List<SubGraphUtil> subGraphUtilList,
                                                   Specification<Contrat> specification);
}
```

Full code: [Here](https://christophe-agoero.developpez.com/tutoriels/java/requete-jpa/)